# How can I upload files asynchronously in Django? Can I use Celery for this purpose? I passed django form to the task and it didn't work

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery

Normally, we can deploy celery for async. Can celery be used for asynchronous file uploading, which allows client to continue working on the website while big size of file being uploaded? I passed the forms to the task of the celery and I had an error like 'Object of type module is not JSON serializable'. Is there any way for async file uploading?

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure it's not possible, what you need to do is more like open a popup page and do the job inside.

`'Object of type module is not JSON serializable'`

One of the best practice of Celery is to stock data in database (for a lot of data), and create a celery task with ID's only. The object you pass to celery need to be `json` formatted.